# How to access associate array of array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm from Perl but I'm beginner in PHP. I'm having following array

```
$rating_data = Array ("51" => Array (5,3,4,2));
```

I'm trying to access the each data using loop so I tried following

```
    foreach ($keys as $rating_data)
    {
        foreach ($index as $rating_data[$keys])
        {
            echo "$index";

        }
    }
```

But the above one is not working. I have also tried the below one also,

```
    $all_keys = array_keys($rating_data);   
    foreach ($keys as $all_keys)
    {
        foreach ($values as $all_keys)
        {
            echo "$values";
        }
    }
```

But I didn't get the output. It works if I hard code the keys like below:

```
$rating_data["51"][0];
```

How to fix this issue.?

Comment: the foreach params are different then you think! [foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: You used the foreach wrong: The syntax is `foreach ($array as $key)`, so you have to put the array you want to loop over at the frist position, **before** the `as`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as below:

```
foreach($rating_data as $key => $values) {
   echo $key;
   foreach($values as $value) {
      echo $value;
   }
}
```

You seem to have your parameters the wrong way around in your `foreach` statements. I would advise a quick read through the [foreach docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Thank you. But while print the $keys it is showing like `Array to string conversion....`?

Comment: `$keys` is an array so you can't print it using `echo`. Please try `var_dump($keys)` or `print_r($keys)` instead

Comment: I'm trying to keys and its values as separate means I'm trying to print keys are one columns all other values are other columns. Using JavaScript I have done. Is it not possible with php?

Comment: Ok I understand now, please see updated answer. You need key, value pairs in your foreach for this

Answer (score 2):

You can get the key position and iter value ( sencod level ).

```
foreach($rating_data as $key => $values)
{
   echo $key; // Output "51"
   foreach($values as $value)
   {
       echo $value; // Output: iter1: "5", iter2: "3", iter3: "4", iter1: "2", 
   }
}
```